# cost price of item

Tags: algebra-precalculus

let us consider following problem:

Roger sold a watch at a profit of $10$%. If he had bought it at $10\%$ less and sold it for $13$  dollar less,then  he would have made a profit of $15$%. What is the cost price of the watch?

suppose that price of watch is $x$ dollar, $profit=sell -cost $

so  let us denote price of watch by $x$,then if he would  buy it $10$ less,then  cost of this would be $x-0.1*x=0.9*x$,  and if it sold  $13$ dollar less,then sold price would be $x-13$, profit is $15$%,then it would be $0.15*x$ right?  or we have

$(x-13)-0.9*x=0.15*x$

but it makes negative equation like  $13=-0.05*x$,so what is my mistake,how can i used information  like Ronger sold watch at a profit of $10\%$? Thanks in advance

Comment: Your mistake is not using that bit of information about the profit. If he paid $x$ for it, then he sold it for $(1.1)x$, not $x$.

Comment: could anybody help me or delete post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have costs $c$ and sell price $p$. We know that he had $10\%$ profit, so $$p-c=0.1c$$
On the other hand, $$(p-13) - 0.9c = 0.15\times0.9c$$
Can you take it from here?

**Edit**

On the calulation of profit:

Profit is the difference between the selling price of the good and costs to create this good. In our case the costs are price of watch when it was bought. So, if the agent of the market buys a good for $p_{buy}$ and then resells it for $p_{sell}$, then the absolute profit is $p_{sell}-p_{buy}$. If we want to calculate our profit in percent, then we take them relatively to the costs (it's logical, because they represent our starting money). We have then the formula for relative profit $$\frac{p_{sell}-p_{buy}}{p_{buy}}\times 100\%.$$

As a numerical example, say you spend $100$USD to purchase a bottle of wine (quite a wine, I must say). You let it age for a couple of years and resell it for $120$USD. Your absolute profit is $$120USD-100USD = 20USD,$$
and your relative profit is $$\frac{120USD-100USD}{100USD}\times 100\%=20\%.$$

Comment: i have  thought differently,if  he made from the beginning $10$  percent profit,and if he would change  something and would made $15$ % profit,thus it m means that  could use  $5$ percent in our equation?

Comment: it should be $0.1*p$ right?suppose   $100$ and $90$,where $100$  price,$90$ cost

Comment: @giorgi Profit is calculated with respect to the price paid to buy, not price he sold it for. In your example the profit is $100/90 -1 \sim 11\%$.

Comment: @giorgi you can't really use those $5\%$, see my comment above.

Comment: sorry how?how is profite calculated

Comment: i absolutely did not understand anything sorry

Comment: please help me with clear example

Comment: in our case how it would be?

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Let Roger has bought the watch at $100x$ dollar

So, the current selling price $=110x$ dollar

If he had bought it at $10$% less, the buying price would have been $=90x$ dollar

If he had sold it for $13$ dollar less, selling price $=110x-13$ dollar

So, $$90x \left(1+\frac{15}{100}\right)=110x-13$$

Comment: i did not understand ,could you be  a little more detailed?

Comment: let take please with numbers

Comment: @giorgi, unless otherwise specified, the selling price is always based on the buying price. Just put $x=1$ or any positive value for that matter  in my answer if you are interested in concrete example

Comment: so let us started  it like this,suppose that   selling price is  $x$  ok?

Comment: if he made  profit  $10$,it means that cost price is $0.9*x$  right?

Comment: @giorgi, as pointed out earlier "the selling price is always based on the buying price" it's easier to start with the buying price.

Comment: but  it is simple for me,so please  do like it

Comment: ok let us start with buying price

Comment: suppose buying or cost price is $x$,then sell  price is $1.1*x$ right

Comment: @rst, yes, just go ahead

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10046/discussion-between-lab-bhattacharjee-and-giorgi)

Comment: i can't  see anything

Comment: this procedure is unclear for me,please  follow step by step

Comment: @giorgi, can't you come to chat?

Comment: no please  talk to chat

Comment: i have spent a lot of time and did not get correct answer

Comment: @ lab bhattacharjee are you here?

Comment: please  finish this problem as soon as possible,is it so difficult? :(

Comment: @giorgi, $$110x-90x\cdot\frac{115}{100}=13\implies \frac{13x}2=13\implies x=2 $$

Comment: i am getting $x$  is equal 200,but in answer there is  220 only

Comment: my equation is $(1.1*x-13)-0.9*x=0.15*0.9*x$ $

Comment: @giorgi, me to got buying price $=200$

Comment: in answers there is not $200$

Comment: cost price is  buying price right

Comment: minimum answer is $220$,which represent as  selling price

Comment: please check it http://www.english-test.net/forum/ftopic20419.html  last problem

Comment: is it in answers mistake or

Comment: http://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100324215215AAnVPlo

Comment: but then why it is  not written $200$ in answers?

Comment: @giorgi, my last statement for this question : please learn the method, don't go by answer

Comment: so it means that answers  are wrong?if this question comes on GRE